# Weird with mesh deformer

Tags: modifiers

This error occurred, when I wanted to mesh deformer apply. How can I fix it? [image: o]Thanks.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/2e242a54063344b68aa4e37e681edd6e

Comment: Here is a file.

Comment: your cage needs to be bigger than your character, maybe make a new one that contains the body properly

Comment: Thanks, I will try!